# Conflicting import, imported name 'Toast' is ambiguous

Tags: java, android, kotlin, checkstyle

Am trying to run a build on Circle CI but am facing this ambiguous checkstyle error in android kotlin, I don't have any Idea why it's happening, below is the error am having :

> /home/circleci/repo/app/src/main/java/com/andela/mrm/util/ConvergeUIUtils.kt:
>   (12, 23): Conflicting import, imported name 'Toast' is ambiguous e:
>   /home/circleci/repo/app/src/main/java/com/andela/mrm/util/ConvergeUIUtils.kt:
>   (14, 23): Conflicting import, imported name 'Toast' is ambiguous

Below is the `ConvergeUIUtils.kt` file :

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.PorterDuff
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.view.Gravity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.andela.mrm.R


/**
 * Important methods for the application UI.
 */
class ConvergeUIUtils
/**
 * Private constructor to prevent instantiation.
 */
private constructor() {
    init {
        throw UnsupportedOperationException()
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Show snackbar with edited properties.
         *
         * @param context the view context.
         * @param view the view to display the snackbar.
         * @param string the message to be displayed.
         */
        fun showSnackBar(context: Context, view: View, string: String) {
            val snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, string, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            val snackbarView = snackbar.view
            snackbarView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 12)
            if (string.contains("extended")) {
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.waiting_color))
            } else {
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                        R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
            }
            snackbar.show()
        }

        /**
         * @param context the view context.
         * @param string the message of the toast.
         */

        fun showToast(context: Context, string: String) {
            val toast = Toast.makeText(context, string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.LEFT, 50, 50)
            val view = toast.view

            if (string.isNullOrBlank()) {

                view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.notification_success_img)
                toast.show()
            } else {

                if (string.contains("extended")) {
                    view.background.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.waiting_color),
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                    val text = view.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.message)
                    text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                } else {
                    view.background.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                            R.color.colorPrimaryDark), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
                }
                val text = view.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.message)
                text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
                toast.show()
            }

        }


        /**
         * set background color for free time button.
         *
         * @param context the view context.
         * @param freeDisplay the free time button.
         */
        fun setButtonColor(context: Context, freeDisplay: ConstraintLayout) {
            val normalDrawable = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_room_extra_time)
            normalDrawable!!.setColorFilter(-0x1, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
            freeDisplay.background = normalDrawable
        }

    }
}
```

How can I overcome this checkstyle error ?

This is picture of the error.

[image]

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: Your imports have multiple classes named `Toast`. You have to use `Toast` with the package name, like `android.widget.Toast.makeText()`

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I tried it but it brings the same error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your imports have multiple classes named `Toast`.

Kotlin supports an alias for imports: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html

```
import android.widget.Toast as WToast
```